# Set chapters at section level in the table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, chapters, bookmarks

I have:

```
\chapter{My first chapter}
\chapter{My second chapter}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendixes}
\appendix
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@chapter{1}\def\toclevel@section{2}
\makeatother
\chapter{My first appendix}
\chapter{My second appendix}
```

So my `hyperref` table of contents looks like:

```
- My first chapter
- My second chapter
+ Appendixes
  - My first appendix
  - My second appendix
```

But my `\tableofcontents` still looks like:

```
1 My first chapter
2 My second chapter
Appendixes
A My first appendix
B My second appendix
```

And what I want is that the appendixes look like sections:

```
1 My first chapter
2 My second chapter
Appendixes
  A My first appendix
  B My second appendix
```

I can figure out, that there is a really small trick to do the job, but I can't find it...

Comment: how about `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendixes}`?
`

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set `\l@chapter` to `l@section`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
\chapter{My second chapter}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendixes}
\appendix
\def\toclevel@chapter{1}\def\toclevel@section{2}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\l@chapter\string \l@section}
\chapter{My first appendix}
\chapter{My second appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this MWE does not work for me. The appendix chapters appear on the same line of the toc and the strings pop up, here is what I copied out of the pdf generated: `@section  lA My rst appendix7  lB My second appendix9`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You can redefine `\@chapter` (as implemented in the document class used) to use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{...}` instead of `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...}`. Here's an example of such redefinition for `book.cls`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
\chapter{My second chapter}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendixes}
\appendix
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother

\chapter{My first appendix}
\chapter{My second appendix}

\end{document}
```

Here's the resulting ToC:

[image]

and the bookmarks pabel:

[image]

Comment: I want it class independant (like Herbert's answer)

Answer (score 4):

The following is a condensed version of Gonzalo's answer, using [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch). It patches the first appearance of `{toc}{chapter}` in `\Hy@org@chapter` with `{toc}{section}`, yielding the same result:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
\chapter{My second chapter}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendixes}
\appendix
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{{toc}{chapter}}{{toc}{section}}{}{}%
\makeatother

\chapter{My first appendix}
\chapter{My second appendix}

\end{document}
```

---

If you wish to not only print the `\chapter`s at section level, but push the entire hierarchy down a level, things get a little more messy. Specifically because the sectional units are all governed by a single macro (perhaps since they're common to all basic document classes) called `\@startsection`. So, one could redefine or patch the "type" or "level" of the macro for each sectional unit. This has no effect on [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). For example:

```
\xpatchcmd{\section}{section}{subsection}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\subsection}{subsection}{subsubsection}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\subsubsection}{subsubsection}{paragraph}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\paragraph}{paragraph}{subparagraph}{}{}
```

Of course, there's no level to demote `\subparagraph`, but hopefully that level of detail is not included in your ToC.

---

If all of the above should be localized so you can easily revert back to the default layout when needed, then I would suggest making a copy of any of the macros *before* patching them:

```
\let\storedchapter\Hy@org@chapter
\let\storedsection\section
\let\storedsubsection\subsection
\let\storedsubsubsection\subsubsection
\let\storedparagraph\paragraph
```

This way you can revert the process later, if needed.

Comment: how do I extend this for lower hierarchy levels (section, subsection, subsubsection,...). Especially what do I do with the lowest hierarchy level to push it one level down? (fortunately the last part is pure curiosity since I dont use it in my toc). Also: can I reverse this effect if I would like to add a chapter with the default hierarchy to the toc afterwards?

Comment: @ted: I've added some detail.

Comment: While one should refrain from tahnk you notes, I have to use one here, since I have already upvoted there is no other way to let you know the effort has not gone unnoticed and is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. It uses the `addcontentsline` to insert the `chapter` on the level you choose, and useses the starred variant to typeset the title with the `chapter` formatting without adding anything to the table of contents.
letltxmacro is used since I get a circular reference otherwise.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
\chapter{My second chapter}

\LetLtxMacro{\chapNoToc}{\chapter*}
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
\chapNoToc*{#1}
\phantomsection
\markboth{#1}{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}

\chapter{My first appendix}
\chapter{My second appendix}

\end{document}
```

This solution could be exteneded to support `chapters` optional argument, however I do not know how to insert the first argument or an otpional argument depending on the presence of the later of the top of my head.

It might be a good idea to save `\chapter` with `\LetLtxMacro` so it can be restored later. Add `\LetLtxMacro{\oldChapter}{\chapter}` before you redfine `\chapter` and use `\LetLtxMacro{\chapter}{\oldChapter}` to restore the default chapter behaviour.

Comment: @lockstep: did I get it right now? (You commented that I was missing the title markings). However my knowledge is from google, so I am unsure if this covers all cases now.